# Excel: NumberFormat for M, -M, 0=" "

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to create a numberformat such that:

- positive millions = "0.0 M",
- negative millions = "-0.0 M",
- Zero = " "

I have struggled to get this.

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Comment: How would 1, 100 or 1000 be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
0.0,, "M";-0.0,, "M";""
```